# Spring JDBC lob insertion fails: Invalid column type

Tags: oracle, spring-jdbc, lob

The code:

```
                jdbcTemplate.update("MERGE INTO app_role_data x USING (select ? name, ? xml FROM dual) d ON (x.app_name = d.name) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET x.xml_blob = d.xml WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(app_name, xml_blob) VALUES(d.name, d.xml)",
                    new AbstractLobCreatingPreparedStatementCallback(lobHandler) {
                            protected void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, LobCreator lobCreator) throws SQLException {
                                    ps.setString(1, appName);
                                    lobCreator.setClobAsString(ps, 2, xmlBlob);
                            }
                    });
```

lobHandler is an instance of OracleLobHandler that's injected in the context.

The exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9231)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8812)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9534)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9517)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:351)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:815)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:586)
```

This is Spring framework 3.0.5.RELEASE.

Our oracle driver dependency is

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

The table:

```
SQL> desc app_role_data
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 APP_NAME                       VARCHAR2(64)
 XML_BLOB                       CLOB
```

I'm not even sure what other information I can add, but I'll be happy to do so if I've left something out.

Comment: This fails the same way with the query simply being "INSERT INTO app_role_data(app_name, xml_blob) VALUES (?,?)"

Comment: Note that this fails with Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE as well. I seriously can't believe that I am the only person in the entire universe that is unable to insert a CLOB into an Oracle 11g database with Spring JDBC 3.x.

Comment: It also fails with the Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, execute() takes a PreparedStatementCallback, while update() takes a PreparedStatementSetter. But both have overloads that take Object, so the compiler doesn't complain.

Grumble. That's a day of my life I'll never get back.

Answer (score 0):

I am being a little skeptical about the column names here

Can you try something like below in your `MERGE`

```
select ? as name, ? as xml FROM dual
```

But I am skeptical of that too since the way you can have dynamic column names is by creating a dynamic sql and executing it with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Or may be something like this (not best in terms of Oracle)-

```
jdbcTemplate.update("MERGE INTO app_role_data x USING dual d ON (x.app_name = ?) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET x.xml_blob = ? WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(app_name, xml_blob) VALUES(?, ?)",......
```

Comment: The failure is identical even if the query is simply "INSERT INTO app_role_data(app_name, xml_blob) VALUES(?,?)"

Comment: can you run `desc app_role_data` and post the output? I am thinking that something is going on with the `CLOB` column.

Comment: looks like your column `xml_blob` is of type `BLOB` and you are creating a `CLOB` using `lobCreator.setClobAsString`. Can you try creating a blob instance using `setBlobAsBytes`? and then use that instead..

Comment: The schema creation script has "create table app_role_data(app_name varchar2(64), xml_blob clob);" to create that table.